# Telegram bot payments connected to Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, telegram-bot

I am trying to make payments through Telegram bots by contacting directly on Telegram. But when I get the "pre_checkout_query" and I answer it (I think correctly), but it gives me error. I leave here the code because I do not know what is wrong.
I have two parts, the first one where I deny the payment simply to be able to test easier if I answer correctly or not and the second one the code that I would use to answer correctly and accept the payment.
I am developing it in Apps Script.
Thanks!

```
  if (contenido.pre_checkout_query != null) {
    tg.enviarMensaje(telegramUrl, idAdri, "dentroif", "HTML")
    var idoperacion = contenido.pre_checkout_query.id
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(telegramUrl + '/answerShippingQuery?shipping_query_id =' + idoperacion + '&ok=False' + "&error_message=Test")


    /*var precios = [
      {
        "label": "Listado Usuarios Karma",
        "amount": "145"
      },
      {
        "label": "Listado Usuarios Karma",
        "amount": "150"
      }
    ]
    var opcionesprecio = [
      {
        "id": idoperacion,
        "title": "Titulo",
        "prices": encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(precios))
      },
    ]
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(telegramUrl + '/answerPreCheckoutQuery?shipping_query_id=' + idoperacion + '&ok=True' + "ShippingOption=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(opcionesprecio)))
*/

  }
```

A possible solution to the problem

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post the full text of the API error response you get when you use the Telegram bot.  That will help in providing a good answer for you.

Comment: Exception: Request failed for https://api.telegram.org returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: query is too old and response timeout expired or query ID is invalid"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)